# Formula for linking a cell on one page to another cell on a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, formula

My current workbook has a summary page that summarizes three hundred different properties that are expanded in sheets in this particular workbook. The summary page includes 3 columns that are to reflect the dates inputted by those who signed the following worksheets.
The tab for my Summary Sheet is called "Summary" and the tab for the Properties depends on the property number. For example, 335, 336, a40, b02, etc.
Every Property sheet has a sign off date by the managers of my company and each date cell is filled out in `f21`, `f25`, and `f29`. When `f21`, `f25`, and `f29` are filled out, I'd like that date to be reflected on the Summary page. The current formula I am using is

=IF('335'!F21<>"", '335'!F21, "")

and I get a random number sequence 440298 rather than the desired and reflected date. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Change the format of the cell to the date format you desire.  `440298` is just the double version of the date.  Excel stores dates as doubles, it is the format of the cell that shows that number in the date format desired.